# Mensaje de guadado exitosamente en base de datos - CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, mensajes

como puedo hacer que aparezca un mensaje de guardado para que el usuario pueda saber que se guardo, estoy haciendo una aplicación que guarda registros solo que al guardalo solo hace un refresh quisiera que un modal o algo para que el usuario sepa que se guardó. He probado poniendo un setf_flashdata,lo hace pero si al momento de validar los otros campos me salo todos como un set_flashdata.

Este es el else del controlador si todo ha ido bien( no os pongo todo el codigo porque creo yo que influya).

```html
else{
            $firma= str_replace(" ", "_", $this->input->post('nombre')).'_'.str_replace(" ", "_", $this->input->post('apellidos')).'_'.date('Y-m-d-H_i_s').'.png';
            $data = array(
                'nombre' =>$this->input->post('nombre'),
                'apellidos'=>$this->input->post('apellidos'),
                'email'=> $this->input->post('email'),
                'ciudad'=> $this->input->post('ciudad'),
                'fecha'=> date('Y-m-d  H:i:s'),
                'condiciones'=> 1,
                'firma'=>$firma,
                'ubicacion'=>$this->input->post('ubicacion'),
                'hotel'=>$this->input->post('hotel')
            );

            // Variables para guardar el canva //
            $img = $this->input->post('datos-img');
            $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
            $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
            $img_data = base64_decode($img);
            $ruta= $this->parametros_model->get_parametros('ruta_firmas');
            $file = $ruta. $firma;
            $success = file_put_contents($file, $img_data);
            $image=str_replace('./','',$file);

            //MAILCHIMP
            $list_id = '0f61ec2abc';//EL HOTEL DEBERÁ PONER EL ListID DONDE GUARDARÁ LOS MAILS AL IGUAL QUE EN APLICATION/CONFIG/CONFIG LINEA 525
            $MailChimp = new MailChimp('APIKEY-us12');
            if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
                $this->mailchimp->verify_ssl = false;
            }
            $result = $this->mailchimp->post("lists/$list_id/members", [
                'email_address' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'merge_fields'  => [
                    'FNAME' =>$this->input->post('nombre'),
                    'LNAME'=>$this->input->post('apellidos'),
                    'CIUDAD'=>$this->input->post('ciudad'),
                    'UBICACION'=>$this->input->post('ubicacion'),
                    'NMHOTEL'=>$this->input->post('hotel'),
                ],
                    'status'=> 'subscribed',
            ]);
            
            

            $this->empleado_model->insertar($data);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('hotel',$hotel);

            if($data){
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Cliente registrado con éxito');
                redirect(base_url('empleado/index'));
            }
            redirect('empleado');
        }
```

Vista
Aquí cargo los campos  del formulario :

```html
<div class="img-centro">
<!--    <img  class="" src="--><?//=base_url('img/').$img?><!--">-->
    <img src="<?=base_url('img/').$img2?>"> <!-- style="margin-left: 75px"  -->
</div>
<hr>
<div class="loader-page"></div>

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <br>
                <br>
                <?php if($this->session->flashdata('success')) { ?>

                    <h5 id="alert_success" class="alert alert-info" role="alert"><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success');?></h5>

                <?php } ?>
                <form  id="form-registry-cliente" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal forla-whith" role="form" method="post"  action="<?=base_url('empleado/insertar')?>">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="prueba1">Nombre y Apellido</label>
                        <div class="row ">
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-special">
                                <input type="text"  id="nombre" name="nombre" class="form-control input-plus"  autocomplete="off" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php echo set_value('nombre')?>"/> <!-- style="margin-left: 35px" -->
                                <?=form_error('nombre', '<div class="alert alert-danger input-plus">', '</div>'); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-special">
                                <input type="text" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" class="form-control input-plus"  autocomplete="off" placeholder="Apellido" value="<?php echo set_value('apellidos')?>"/>
                                <?=form_error('apellidos', '<div class="not-same-input  alert alert-danger input-plus">', '</div>'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group prueba">
                        <label>E-mail</label>
                        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" class="form-control formu-width" placeholder="Correo Electrónico" value="<?php echo set_value('email')?>"/>
                        <?=form_error('email', '<div class="same-input alert alert-danger">', '</div>'); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group prueba">
                        <label>Ciudad</label>
                        <input type="text" id="ciudad" name="ciudad" autocomplete="off" class="form-control formu-width"  placeholder="Ciudad" value="<?php echo set_value('ciudad')?>"/>
                        <?=form_error('ciudad', '<div class="same-input alert alert-danger">', '</div>'); ?>
                    </div>
                        <input type="hidden" id="hotel" name="hotel" readonly class="form-control"  value="<?= $nmhotel ?>"/>
                    <div class="">
                        <select name="ubicacion" id="ubicacion" class="" style=" visibility: hidden ">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="sintonia" <?php if ($localizacion =='sintonio'){?> selected<?php } ?>>Sintonia</option>
                            <option value="the-top_gallery_hotel" <?php if ($localizacion =='top_gallery'){?> selected<?php } ?>>The Top GH</option>
                            <option value="Matiz" <?php if ($localizacion =='Matiz'){?> selected<?php } ?>>Matiz</option>
                            <option value="the_top_molina_lario" <?php if ($localizacion =='top_molina'){?> selected<?php } ?>>The Top ML</option>
                            <option value="Salicornia" <?php if ($localizacion =='Salicornia'){?> selected<?php } ?>>Salicornia</option>
                            <option value="the_top_honucai" <?php if ($localizacion =='top_honucai'){?> selected<?php } ?>>The Top HH</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group prueba">
                        <label>Firma</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group prueba" >
                        <canvas id="signature" name="signature" width="355" height="150" style="border: 1px solid #ddd;" class="sig-canvas"></canvas>
                        <br>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary " id="clear-signature">Limpiar Firma</a>
                    </div>

                <!--Input donde se guarda la imagen del canva en codigo 64 -->
                    <input type="hidden" id="datos-img" name="datos-img" value="">

                    <div class="form-check prueba botton">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="terminos" id="terminos" value="acepta" data-toggle="modal">
                        <label class="form-check-label c-white" for="terminos">Acepto los términos y condiciones <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"style="color: red"></span></label>
                        <?=form_error('terminos', '<div class="alert alert-danger all-input">', '</div>'); ?>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="hotel" name="hotel" value="<?= $hotel ?>"/>

                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <a class="btn btn-info prueba2" href=<?php echo base_url('principal')?>> <strong> < </strong> Volver</a>
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-derecha" value="registrar">Guardar</button>
                        <a class="btn btn-warning derecha prueba3" href=<?php echo base_url('exportacion')?>> Reporting</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal Condiciones -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="politicaprivacidad" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="aceptacion de condiciones" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle" style="color: black;font-weight: normal;">Política de privacidad   <span style="color: black;font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $nmhotel ?></span></h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p style="color: black;line-height:25px;text-justify: auto;font-size: 1.2rem"><?php echo $condiciones ?> <a href="https://<?= $url ?>"> <?= $url ?></a> </p>
                    <br>
                    <div class="collapse" id="containerFiltro">
                        <p style="color: black;line-height:25px;text-justify: auto;font-size: 1.2rem"><?php echo $ingles ?> <a href="https://<?= $url ?>"> <?= $url ?></a> </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button  class="btn btn-raised btn-warning ripple float-left"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#containerFiltro"  type="button">View in english</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).on('load', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".loader-page").css({visibility:"hidden",opacity:"0"})
    }, 2000);
    set_background();
    specialclass();
    });

    // BACKGROUND DE CADA FORMULARIO
    function set_background(){
        var ubicacion = $('#ubicacion option:checked').val();
        var clase = '';

        switch (ubicacion){
            case 'sintonia':
                clase = 'gh-sintonia';
              break;
            case 'the-top_gallery_hotel':
                clase = 'gh-top';
              break;
            case 'Matiz':
                clase = 'molinala-matiz';
                break;
            case 'the_top_molina_lario':
                clase = 'molinala-top';
                break;
            case 'Salicornia':
                clase = 'hh-salicornia';
                break;
            case 'the_top_honucai':
                clase = 'hh-top';
                break;
            default:
                clase = 'gh-sintonia';
        }
        $('.container').addClass(clase);
    }

   //LOGO DE LA UBICACIÓN
    function specialclass(){

        var ubicacion = $('#ubicacion option:checked').val();
        var clase = '';

        switch (ubicacion){
            case 'sintonia':
                clase = 'normals';
                break;
            case 'the-top_gallery_hotel':
                clase = 'topgh';
                break;
            case 'Matiz':
                clase = 'normalm';
                break;
            case 'the_top_molina_lario':
                clase = 'topml';
                break;
            case 'Salicornia':
                clase = 'normalsl';
                break;
            case 'the_top_honucai':
                clase = 'tophh';
                break;
            default:
                clase = 'normals';
        }
        $('.img-centro').addClass(clase);

    }

    // JQUERY DEL CANVAS
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        var canvas = document.getElementById("signature");
        var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);

        $('#clear-signature').on('click', function(){
            signaturePad.clear();
        });
    //Funcion donde guardara en un input type hidden el codigo base64 que generará el propio canva
        function getSignaturePad() {
            var imageData = signaturePad.toDataURL();
            document.getElementById("datos-img").setAttribute("value", imageData);
        }
        //Al momento que se envie el formulario que se guarde en la carpeta del servidor la imagen generada en el canva
        $('#form-registry-cliente').submit(function() {
            getSignaturePad(); //Carga la funcion donde se genera la funcion donde se guarda la imagen
            return true;
        });
    });

    //CHECKBOX MODAL
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(e){
        if (e.target.checked) {
            $('#politicaprivacidad').modal();
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#alert_success').delay(5000).slideUp(100);
    });

</script>
```

Forma como lo hace si le doy a guardar si rellenar ningun campo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hacer esto sin que se "dañen los mensajes de validación"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías incluir una especie de barra de información en la parte superior o inferior de tu pantalla donde mostrar ese mensaje. Los modales son del siglo pasado y obligan al usuario a acciones suplementarias, como cerrar el modal, rompiendo además la sintonía. Es más elegante mostrar una barra informativa integrada a la misma ventana. Además ahora con herramientas como Ajax puedes comunicar con el servidor y actualizar elementos sin tener que recargar la página.

Comment: Puedes usar este plugin para generar notificaciones https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html